# PostgreSQL - SUM true-false column & group by month giving me a percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean

i have a table with id and some other data that I already filtered.
first I wanted to know how I convert into a new table that output

```
select A, B from Table
where B between '2020-03-01' and '2020-04-30'
order by B ASC
;
```

i have this output like this:

```
A       B
1    12-03-2000
0    12-04-2000
1    03-02-2000
1    04-02-2000
0    02-05-2001
```

my interest is focused only on 2 months
i want to know the percentage represents the sum of both true & false (separately) in each month

Comment: Your question is really hard to follow.  The dates don't match.  Where does 33.99% come from?

Comment: I already know the real result, but I can't solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the months in columns with the percent true and false for each month.  That uses conditional aggregation:

```
select A,
       count(*) filter (where month(b) = 3) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) filter (where extract(month from b) = 3) as march,
       count(*) filter (where extract(month from b) = 4) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) filter (where month(b) = 4) as april
from Table
where B between '2020-03-01' and '2020-04-30'
group by A;
```

Comment: it gives me an error, but yes, I want the months in columns like you said

ERROR:  function month(date) does not exist
LINE 2:        count(*) filter (where month(fec_alta) = 3) / sum(cou...
                                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @FrancoMica . . . For arcane reasons, I defined `year()`, `month()`, and `day()` function on my local version of Postgres.  Sometimes I forget they are not built in.

Comment: @FrancoMica . . . Just using `extract()`.